# Joomla 3 scrollbar not working anymore

Tags: joomla

I dunno what happened but the scrollbar is not working anymore.

Here's the link of the proof.

What could be?

http://www.anticamaddalena.it/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=72&Itemid=472

Tank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

you're loading two times the jQuery library and the second time it rewrites the jQuery object so it looses the "draggable" that you need for your scrollbar.
Check if you can disable jQuery from the module "mod_backgroundrotator" you're already loading it in your template you don't need it twice.

Comment: huh, ok let's try with this plugin: http://www.joomlabamboo.com/joomla-extensions/jb-library-plugin-a-free-joomla-jquery-plugin install it and enable the "remove jQuery" option, it will load jQuery in all pages only one time and remove any other jQuery library include. Let me know if this did the trick ;)